# Android room insertion failling

Tags: android, dao, android-room

So I've been struggling with Room for a few days trying to understand how this should be done

My entity

```
@Entity(
        foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(
                entity = Movie.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "movieId")
        },
        indices = @Index("movieId")
)
@TypeConverters(MovieConverter.class)
public class UpcomingMovies {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo
    public int movieId;

    @ColumnInfo
    public Movie movie;
}
```

Dao insertion method

```
@Insert
void insertUpcomingMovies(List<Movie> movies);
```

I have an auxilary method to let me know if I have data in this table, but it keeps returning 0

```
@Query("Select count(*) FROM UpcomingMovies")
LiveData<Integer> countUpcoming();
```

What am I doing wrong ? Does `UpcomingMovies` need a `List<Movie> movies` ? My reasoning here is that every entry in `UpcomingMovies` will have a `Movie`, so I only need one `Movie` instance, hence in the insertion I'm passing a `List<Movie>`. Is my reasoning incorrect ?

The result I was expecting would be smth like

- UpComingId -- MovieId --  Movie ( Movie stringified)
- 1   ; 33     ;   { .. Name: Jurassic Park , id: 33 ...}
- 2   ;        77  ;      { .. Name: Mission possible , id: 77 .... }

Somebody give me some insight if you please

Comment: Please try with array of movies @Insert
long insertUpcomingMovies(Movie... movies); and instead of void return long to check the count of rows inserted

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Tried it, but it gives an error error: Method returns long but it should return one of the following: `void, long[], java.lang.Long[], java.util.List<java.lang.Long>`. If you want to return the list of row ids from the query, your insertion method can receive only 1 parameter.

Comment: try @Insert long[] insertUpcomingMovies(Movie... movies);

Comment: The array change did not seem necessary. But I'm seeing that it's inserting the rows now with the diferent return type. So my guess is, I've wired up my `LiveData` poorly ?

Comment: I don't have much idea about LiveData as I use Rxjava instead, but check how you are using the LiveData<Integer>, It Works With Single<Integer>